# Why isn't null a compile time constant?

Tags: java, null, bytecode

So if I have a `static final Object CONSTANT = null`, for some reason if I reference that in another piece of code like `doSomething(CONSTANT)`, it won't be in-lined onto the code during compilation. So instead of being `doSomething(null)` after being compiled, it would be `doSomething(CONSTANT)`.

Comment: how sure are you? have you looked at the bytecode or at the optimized code after JIT?

Comment: Yeah, I saw the bytecode outline on IntelliJ.

Comment: the thing is the java doesnt really optimize at the bytecode level, all of the optimizations are in the JIT, so this is an issue only if youre running without JIT

Comment: I thought Java (7) already has a JIT built inside it.

Comment: could be disabled, could be using other JVMs ...

Comment: Nope, it's not disabled, and I'm 100% sure I'm using 7's JVM.

Comment: @radai yes but it still inlines static final constants (and initializes them with ConstantValue attributes). ConstantValue doesn't support null, but they could still conceivably be inlined. It's really a question for the language designers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your `CONSTANT` is not a compile time constant because the JLS *says* it is not.  The only types that can be used in constant expressions are the primitive types and `String`.

The sense of it is that an `Object` instance (in general) has a semantically significant object identity that distinguishes it from other `Object` instances.  This Object identity cannot be encoded in a class file ... or at least, it can't be encoded with the current classfile formats.  (And if it could, there would be all sorts of other problems ...)

The value `null` could (in theory) be handled as a special case, except that there is not a great deal of point.  Specifically, you can't use `null` in any of the contexts where a "compile time constant" is required (or advantageous) from the linguistic perspective.  For instance:

- You can't have `null` as a `case` expression.
- Since `==` for reference types is not a constant expression, you can't use it for the Java "conditional compilation" idiom involving an `if` with a constant expression as a condition.  (And besides `null == null` is not a useful condition ...)

As far as inlining is concerned, while the "constant" cannot be inlined in the bytecodes (because of the JLS rules about what a "constant expression" is), the JIT compiler's optimizer would be permitted to do this, and *may* actually do it ... if there are tangible performance benefits.

Reference:

- [JLS 15.28 - Constant Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

Comment: The only place where a compile time null would be required, is as the default value of an java Annotation

Comment: The correct answer is really only "because the JLS says it is not". Some of the other parts are slightly misleading or incorrect, e.g. using `final String s = null` will still not make it a constant either, even though the type of the variable is `String`; because `null` can never be a compile-time constant. And while `null == null` cannot be used for conditional compilation, `"" == ""` can be used, at least in Java 16.

Answer (score 4):

In your case the *CONSTANT* is not compile time constant.

> Compile-time constant is  a constant and its value is known at compile time and
>   it won’t change further, then the compiler replaces the constant name everywhere 
>   in the code with its value .

Generally a primitive type or a string literal that is declared with final is treated as compile time constant by the compiler.
Example:

```
final int a=10;
final String constant =”this is compile time const”;
```

> These both are compile time constants we can use Compile-time constant expressions in case labels of switch statements

Example for non compile time constants

```
final String xyz = new String(”this is not a compile time const");
```

> here xyz string object is not a compile time constant.Because this 'xyz' string object is going to create at run time and here compiler knows about the reference only not the string object.

The same is applicable to your **static final Object CONSTANT = null**

Accroding to [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

> Type of the null literal is the null type;its value is the null reference.