# Java 7 - null as case expression

Tags: java

Why is this failing to compile with an error of "case expressions must be constant expressions"? Isn't `null` a constant (known at compile time)? 
Explicitly casting the `null` value to String as in `case ((String)null)` does not help too (I get the same error).

```
public static String getTypeOfDayWithSwitchStatement(String dayOfWeekArg) {
    String typeOfDay;
    switch (dayOfWeekArg) {

        case null:
            typeOfDay = "NULL";
            break;

        case "Monday":
            typeOfDay = "Start of work week";
            break;
        case "Tuesday":
        case "Wednesday":
        case "Thursday":
            typeOfDay = "Midweek";
            break;
        case "Friday":
            typeOfDay = "End of work week";
            break;
        case "Saturday":
        case "Sunday":
            typeOfDay = "Weekend";
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid day of the week: " + dayOfWeekArg);
    }
    return typeOfDay;
}
```

Comment: Related: [Why isn't null a compile time constant?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17758796/1065197)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28

Comment: @BrunoParmentier Useful link too. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263489/why-doesnt-string-switch-statement-support-a-null-case/18264731#18264731

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the case expressions must be constant expressions, but `null` is specifically prohibited by the [JLS, Section 14.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11), which describes the `switch` statement:

> **Given a switch statement, all of the following must be true or a compile-time error occurs:**
>
> - Every case constant associated with the switch statement must be assignment compatible with the type of the switch statement's Expression (§5.2).
> - If the type of the switch statement's Expression is an enum type, then every case constant associated with the switch statement must be an enum constant of that type.
> - No two of the case constants associated with the switch statement have the same value.
> - *No case constant associated with the switch statement is null*.
> - At most one default label is associated with the switch statement.

(italics emphasis mine)

As a workaround, you can test for `null` outside of the `switch` statement.

Comment: I see, it's in the JLS. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The switch statement will throw a `NullPointerException` if you pass it a null value.  Use a [separate test to check for null values.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: It will indeed throw NPE but I have to compile it first (e.g. by removing that case null statement). So I find this relevant too. Thanks.