# Why does invoking a method on a null reference compile successfully?

Tags: java, exception, compilation

Trying to execute this piece of code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Main();
    }

    Main() {
        A a = null;
        a.foo();
    }
}

class A {
    void foo() {}
}
```

I will get, obviously, a `NullPointerException` since A has been initialized to `null`. The code compiles because I (the coder) know that the variable `a` can only be null at this location, while it (the compiler)... well, actually it knows that too, to the point that I get the warning message

```
Null pointer access: The variable a can only be null at this location
```

My question is, given that both me and it know that an exception is going to be thrown, why is my code allowed to compile? Is there any chance not to get an exception there?

### EDIT:

Put in another way, why do I get a compiler error in someting like this

```
    try {
        throw new Exception();
        int x = 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

and not in this

```
    try {
        if(true)throw new Exception();
        int x = 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Put very poorly: how does the compiler discriminates between blocking or not blocking "obvious errors"?

Comment: You're allowed to _try_ and call `foo()` on a null variable.

Comment: I suspect that this is allowed to let you create some temporary template of execution.

Comment: @khelwood I know that I am allowed because I just did it. I was just curious about the "philosophy" behind that, appearing to me a bit counterintuitive

Comment: @LuigiCortese Kudos to you for editing your quesiton 1 hour after you posted it when there were already some good answers that answered your original quesiton. I mus say that you really understand how this site works ;) Post a quesiton-get answers-ok got my answer->edit question with new question->get answer->ok got my answer-> and so on.. ;)

Comment: what if I'm just very stupid?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as too broad since the OP is asking too many questions in one question.

Comment: @LuigiCortese *I'm sure understand SO better than anyone else*. Then you should know that your question is too broad. Your original question was a good one. This question asks too many questions in one quesiton. You should split them across multiple questions. I am sure it will be closed soon because both your questions are unrelated and have a completely different explanation.

Comment: I meant to write "I'm sure YOU understand so better than anyone else". My doubt was about compiler behaviour when dealing with *obvious* errors, not a specific case. Maybe I'm wrong, but that's why I edited the question

Answer (score 3):

It's allowed to compile as Java Language Specification does not forbid it. Who knows, probably you want to catch this `NullPointerException` in the caller. That would be not the best code design, but it's allowed by JLS.

Note that Eclipse compiler can be configured to display an error at this point. By default it issues a warning:

```
$ java -jar org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.10.2.v20150120-1634.jar -source 1.7 -cp rt.jar Main.java
----------
1. WARNING in L:\Lan\Projects\JavaTest\EcjTest\src\Main.java (at line 8)
       a.foo();
        ^
Null pointer access: The variable a can only be null at this location
----------
1 problem (1 warning)
```

Also static code analyzers like FindBugs will trigger a warning on this code.

The question why it is not forbidden by JLS would be opinion based. However note that such feature cannot be added now, because this may break the backwards compatibility. I believe, there's an existing code which may actually rely on such behavior.

Comment: I believe the quesiton is *Why does the JLS not forbid it*? The OP seems to know it's not a compilation error so it's implied that the language does not forbid it.

Comment: I don't know how to feel about answers like "*this is not forbidden because it is allowed (by some precise specification)*". Technically such answers are correct but I still am not sure if question has been answered fully.

Comment: @ChetanKinger, added a note about this

Comment: @Pshemo: the point of my answer is not that it's allowed by JLS, but that you can create a valid program using this (if you catch and handle NPE later). That would surely be weird, but there are millions of ways to write a weird code and compiler cannot yell on every weird piece of code. And where the compiler should stop is a opinion-based.

Comment: @TagirValeev Your answer does not answer the question at all so I believe you should be subtracting your answer from mine ;) Thanks for the up vote though.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, given that both me and it know that an exception is going to be thrown, why is my code allowed to compile

`null` is not a [compile time constant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). The compiler does not know at compile time that `A a = null;` evaluates to `null`.

Further reading :

[Why isn't null a compile time constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758796/why-isnt-null-a-compile-time-constant)

Answer (score 1):

From  [Java spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.2)

**4.12.2**

> A variable of a class type T can hold a null reference or a reference
>   to an instance of class T or of any class that is a subclass of T.

Also,
For instance consider :

```
         while(true)
        {
        //stay blank
        }
```

This gives error in my NetBeans that following line is unreachable.

Again,

```
       while(true)
        {
           if(false)break;
        }
```

Now what you expect?Same thing? Its not.It goes into infinite loop.
Similarly, you should be able to catch NPE in your code.It is allowed.And so there might exist many combinations for different type of such ambiguity.Which is rather difficult to choose & restrict.

Comment: Well, this `try{ throw new Exception(); int x=0; } catch(Exception e){}` won't compile because `int x=0;` is an unreachable instruction. And it's detected at compile time

Comment: @LuigiCortese  now try this `try{ 
     if(true)
     throw new Exception(); 
 int x=0; 
 } catch(Exception e){}`

Comment: Yeah, i get a warning for dead code... that's nice, I think... I understand why, but a bit confusing anyway

Comment: @LuigiCortese Was your question about getting a warning or why does it not result in a compilation error? As far as I understand, you asked *My question is, given that both me and it know that an exception is going to be thrown, why is my code allowed to compile*

Comment: Well, both! Why do I get a warning even though I would expect to have an error, given that everyone (me and the compiler) knows that there's a problem there?

Comment: @LuigiCortese Your quesiton does not seem to be asking about warning at all.

Comment: @ChetanKinger are you sure about that? javac has even a *-nowarn* option to prevent getting warning messages

Comment: @LuigiCortese I am pretty sure about not getting a NPE warning in your example with plain old `javac` Anyway, has your question that you asked in the question been answered?

Answer (score 1):

I May not be fully correct, But the parsers are to be blamed.I implemented a `Java parser 1.5` which basically calls a `compilationUnit()`.This gets started by getting the stream of the source .

The stream is tokenised (creates tokens -keywords,variables..all smaller parts).It may then make several calls- EG if the Java program has to start with a keyword, it may then look for a access specifier then.After that, the parser need to have the keyword "class".It the find other possibilities after the key word. EG. I may write `public class{}` or `public int i;`.If it gets the correct keyword, parsing continues else a `ParseException` is thrown.

For instance I made a small change in the Parser:

```
private Token jj_consume_token(int kind) throws ParseException {   
        Token oldToken;
        if ((oldToken = token).next != null) {
            token = token.next;
        } else {
            token = token.next = token_source.getNextToken();
        }
        jj_ntk = -1;
        if (token.kind == kind) {
            jj_gen++;
            if (++jj_gc > 100) {
                jj_gc = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < jj_2_rtns.length; i++) {
                    JJCalls c = jj_2_rtns[i];
                    while (c != null) {
                        if (c.gen < jj_gen) {
                            c.first = null;
                        }
                        c = c.next;
                    }
                }
            }

            return token;
        }

        jj_kind = kind;
        throw generateParseException();

        } 
    }
```

To:

```
private Token jj_consume_token(int kind) throws ParseException {

        try{
        Token oldToken;
        if ((oldToken = token).next != null) {
            token = token.next;
        } else {
            token = token.next = token_source.getNextToken();
        }
        jj_ntk = -1;
        if (token.kind == kind) {
            jj_gen++;
            if (++jj_gc > 100) {
                jj_gc = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < jj_2_rtns.length; i++) {
                    JJCalls c = jj_2_rtns[i];
                    while (c != null) {
                        if (c.gen < jj_gen) {
                            c.first = null;
                        }
                        c = c.next;
                    }
                }
            }

            return token;
        }
        token = oldToken;
        jj_kind = kind;
        throw generateParseException();
           } catch (ParseException ex) {
            recover(ex,SEMICOLON);
            return token;
        } 
    }
```

Recovery block looks like:

```
void recover(ParseException ex, int recoveryPoint) {
        syntaxErrors.add(ex);
        Token t;
        do {
            t = getNextToken();
        } while (t.kind != EOF && t.kind != recoveryPoint);
    }
```

So what I just did? I recovered the exception thrown by the parser even if there is no method or just statements.EG

```
class A{
Date d;
System.out.print("No exception");
}
```

I don't get error now.I made changes.So, if you want your parser to report an Exception in such cases, you can implement your parser :) hope you get it now.